# Generate REST API Calls by identifying difference in data

Tags: json, rest

A user enters some data in a text area which is parsed according to a grammar and converted to JSON objects. The parser is triggered every time the the data is changed and it reparses the whole text and regenerates the JSON objects. I need to regularly save these JSON object using REST API calls. Basically I need to identify the differences between the current and last saved data and generate individual POST, PUT and DELETE calls so that existing data is updated without removing the whole data and saving it again.

[Google Fusion Table](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) might to be a solution to my problem but I am not very sure and I don't prefer using that.

Comment: Do you have just one JSON object representing your textarea or do you have multiple JSON objects? Is your goal to determine when a JSON object has changed? Can you be more specific with what you mean by "so that existing data is updated without removing the whole data and saving it again"?

Comment: Text area is parsed to return multiple objects.

e.g.
Text area contains:
`this is obj1
this is multi obj:
-ob1
-ob2`

Parser Returns:
`JSON Object 1 : obj1
JSON Object 2 : ob1
JSON Object 3 : ob2`

Now I change the text area contents to following:
`this is obj2
this is obj3
this is multi obj:
-ob1`


Parser Now Returns:
`JSON Object 1 : obj2
JSON Object 2 : obj3
JSON Object 3 : ob1`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is your asking, but if your goal is to compare JSON objects in order to detect a change in data, you can maintain a hash of each most recent object, compute the hash of the object with which you want to compare it, and then compare the hashes. `JSON.stringify()` would technically be a way of doing this, since you'd be performing a string comparison. Though you would certainly want to look for a more robust hashing mechanism.